# How to mark non mandatory element in xml

Tags: xml, soap

I need to compare actual mock request and expected.
One element is not mandatory and sometimes appear sometimes not - it is correct.
How to add this element to expected xml, that step is not failed if element not presented in actual request.
I get 
`<element1>aaa</element1>
<element2>bbb</element2>
<element3>ccc</element3> 
<element4>ddd</element4>`
OR
`<element1>aaa</element1>
<element2>bbb</element2>
<element4>ddd</element4>`
In both cases correct.
How to ignore element3?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to give you a useful answer.  Review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then come back and edit your question and you will likely see better results.